# Array in PHP,Json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a problem with array in php at json_encode.

I have 2 arrays that work in PHP but only $ testArray works when converting to json_encode.

When output in array in php everything works as it should.
But when converting to json, only one works.

Output is the same for both.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["Autor"] !== "" && $row["Nazev"] !== "")
    {
    $knih_data = [
    "Autor" => "".$row["Autor"]."",
    "Nazev" => "".$row["Nazev"]."",
    "Poznamka" => "".$row["Poznamka"]."",    
    ];
    $knihovna[] = $knih_data;    
    }
}
}





$testArray = [
    [
      "Autor"   => "Autor",
      "Nazev" => " Testuju"
    ],
    [
      "Autor"   => "Autor 2",
      "Nazev" => "Testuju..2",
     "Poznamka" => "Text.. 2"
    ],
    [
      "Autor"   => "Autor 3",
      "Nazev" => "Testuju 3",
      "Poznamka" => "Text.. 3"
    ]
  ];

print_r($testArray); //Work
print_r($knihovna); //Work



  $json_convert = json_encode($testArray);//Work
  echo $json_convert;

  $json_convert = array_values($knihovna);//Notwork
  echo $json_convert;
```

**Output**

```
  Array//testArray
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Někdo
        [Nazev] =>  Zlep�ov�n� podnikov�ch proces
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Někdo 2
        [Nazev] => Testuju..2
        [Poznamka] => Text.. 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Někdo 3
        [Nazev] => Testuju 3
        [Poznamka] => Text.. 3
    )
```

)

```
Array //Knihovna
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Jan Urban
        [Nazev] => 10 nejdra���ch mana�ersk�ch ch
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Forbes
        [Nazev] => ?�slo 3/2013
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Jaroslav Charv�t
        [Nazev] => Firemn� strategie pro praxi
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Nierenberg, Calero, Grayson
        [Nazev] => How to read a person like a bo
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Jim Collins, Jerry I. Porras
        [Nazev] => Jak vybodovat trvale �sp?�nou 
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Miller, Wrobleski, Villafuerte
        [Nazev] => Kultura kaizen
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Simon Synek
        [Nazev] => L�d?i jed� posledn�
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Dan Roam
        [Nazev] => N�pady na ubrousku: ?e�te prob
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Chris Voss, Tahl Raz
        [Nazev] => Nikdy ned?lej kompromis
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Keith Ferrazzi
        [Nazev] => Nikdy nejez s�m
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Simon Synek
        [Nazev] => Objevte sv� pro?
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Michal Martoch 
        [Nazev] => ?�zen� vzd�len�ch pracovn�k?
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Roman Baj?an
        [Nazev] => Techniky public relations aneb
        [Poznamka] => 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [Autor] => Alena Svozilov�
        [Nazev] => Zlep�ov�n� podnikov�ch proces?
        [Poznamka] => 
    )
```

)

There is all ouput in array with print_R

Comment: If you print $knihovna what do you have as output? Maybe your condition never evaluates to true because of there any results our your query is wrong.

Comment: Output is the same in both arrays.

Comment: You're doing a array_values($knihovna) instead of json_encode.

Comment: @TheGridCoder, please do `var_dump($arrayhere)` of two arrays and put it to your post

Comment: I am thinking this might have to do with the double sets of quotes:  -->  `"Autor" => "".$row["Autor"].""`  --  What happens if you set a variable IE `$autor = $row["Autor"]`  And then use that `variable` in double quotes like so: `"Autor" => "$autor",` ??

Comment: This is a character encoding issue: `json_encode` expects the argument to be UTF8 encoded, but seeing from the �-characters in the `print_r` output, those strings are using another encoding. Convert with one of the conversion functions in PHP. Check out `mb_convert_encoding`, `utf8_encode` and `iconv`.

Comment: @trincot - my thoughts too, try `echo json_last_err_msg()` -  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: I m   insert data to table from Excel from google.. how character encoding ?

Comment: **character encoding** - is the bane of many a developer.  And the reason there is no PHP6 ... lol  So your not alone there.  Microsoft Office is especially bad in this regard.  So that is no surprise.  The good old `MSWIN1252` quotes and all that...  If your getting it from a DB you can try setting the character encoding on your connection, sometimes that works.  You can nuke them with `preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/','',$string)` but you probably don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like encoding error. To make sure, you can check what's wrong by printing json_last_error() after json_encode()